# Ionic Facebook Auth - App Not Setup

Tags: ionic-framework, facebook-authentication

I am trying to setup facebook auth in my ionic application. I have a login button that says "Login with Facebook". When the app is deployed to the web, then a facebook popup appears and I can login no problem. It works perfect.

However, it does not work when its running on mobile i.e. when it is using Cordova plugin.

I have setup @ionic-native/facebook. I have setup my facebook app correctly (I can login using Facebook auth on the web app). I have checked it 100 times via the web. Its public etc. etc. I can login using any fb profile.

However, when I run my ionic app on emulator and try to do a facebook login, I am taken to the facebook login screen that says: "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don’t have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permission.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://developers.facebook.com -> your app -> App Review -> turn on 'Make  public'
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply mohammad. Its already public. The app is setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the app is already public and facebook application ID is corrrect, remove platform and add it back. This will update all the references in the code.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova platform add android
```